# Plunker . How to require a react module?

Tags: reactjs, plunker

I am trying to require a react React module on [plnkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/MYkQw2) in the script.jsx file using :

```
var AptList = require('./AptList');
```

Which is giving a "require is not defined" error.

I would like to know how to require modules on [plnkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/MYkQw2?p=info) ?

Comment: do you use `sustemjs` in your code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not using any bundler, everything is in the browser, so you have to first include the **script** for that AptList component in your `index.html`:

```
<script src="AptList.js"></script>
<script src="script.jsx"></script>
```

That will already include the definition for that component. You need not (and cannot) use require there.

In `AptList.js` you need not have `module.exports = AptList;` because it will already have been imported using the script tag above. Also, you should remove the require inside script.jsx.

Now, the other big issue is you are using **JSX**, which is not supported natively by the browser. For that, you will need Babel, so add the following the scripts in index.html:

```
<script src="https://unpkg.com/babel-standalone@6/babel.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.6.1/react.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.6.1/react-dom.js"></script>
```

Then, you have to add the following **type** to each script tag at the bottom, before the end of body:

```
<script type="text/babel" src="..."></script>
```

That will allow you to use ES6 syntax and JSX.

[Here is the link to the plunk with everything working.](https://plnkr.co/edit/wJhNoH0ZseKaQOMeWiPH?p=preview)

Comment: wow...thanks..it worked .. What If I want to use some library like lodash    
 var _ = require('lodash') ;  how would I use lodash on Plnkr

Comment: @RohitasBehera you need only include the script tag for that, for example using the src  `https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.4/lodash.js`